# Перезаписать массив

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, у меня есть вложенные массивы:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title_ru] => Сиделка
        [description_ru] => Уход за пожилыми людьми, помощь больным и не самостоятельным
        [meta_desc_ru] => Уход за пожилыми людьми, помощь больным и не самостоятельным
        [meta_key_ru] => 
        [title_en] => Nurse
        [description_en] => Care for the elderly, the sick and not an independent
        [meta_desc_en] => Care for the elderly, the sick and not an independent
        [meta_key_en] => 
        [title_it] => Badante
        [description_it] => La cura per gli anziani, i malati e non indipendente
        [meta_desc_it] => La cura per gli anziani, i malati e non indipendente
        [meta_key_it] => 
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title_ru] => Уборки
        [description_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
        [meta_desc_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
        [meta_key_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
        [title_en] => Cleaning
        [description_en] => Cleaning houses, cleaning offices and apartments, cleaning in the stairwell
        [meta_desc_en] => Cleaning houses, cleaning offices and apartments, cleaning in the stairwell
        [meta_key_en] => Cleaning houses, cleaning offices and apartments, cleaning in the stairwell
        [title_it] => Pulizia
        [description_it] => Pulizia di uffici e appartamenti di pulizia, la pulizia nella tromba delle scale
        [meta_desc_it] => Pulizia di uffici e appartamenti di pulizia, la pulizia nella tromba delle scale
        [meta_key_it] => Pulizia di uffici e appartamenti di pulizia, la pulizia nella tromba delle scale
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title_ru] => Недвижимость
        [description_ru] => Объявления по недвижимости, продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, комнат. Тут, вы быстро найдете себе крышу над головой!
        [meta_desc_ru] => Объявления по недвижимости, продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, комнат. Тут, вы быстро найдете себе крышу над головой!
        [meta_key_ru] => продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, съем или сдача комнаты
        [title_en] => The property
        [description_en] => Classifieds real estate, apartments for sale, renting or renting apartments, rooms. Here, you will quickly find yourself a roof over his head!
        [meta_desc_en] => Classifieds real estate, apartments for sale, renting or renting apartments, rooms. Here, you will quickly find yourself a roof over his head!
        [meta_key_en] => apartments for sale, renting or renting apartments
        [title_it] => Immobili
        [description_it] => Annunci immobiliari, appartamenti in vendita, noleggio o affitto di appartamenti, camere. Qui, si rapidamente trovare te stesso un tetto sopra la testa!
        [meta_desc_it] => Annunci immobiliari, appartamenti in vendita, noleggio o affitto di appartamenti, camere. Qui, si rapidamente trovare te stesso un tetto sopra la testa!
        [meta_key_it] => appartamenti in vendita, noleggio o affitto di appartamenti, camere
    )
)
```

но я хочу перезаписать его чтоб он был в таком виде:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [title_ru] => Сиделка
        [description_ru] => Уход за пожилыми людьми, помощь больным и не самостоятельным
        [meta_desc_ru] => Уход за пожилыми людьми, помощь больным и не самостоятельным
        [meta_key_ru] => 
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [title_ru] => Уборки
        [description_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
        [meta_desc_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
        [meta_key_ru] => Уборки домов, уборка квартир и офисов, уборка в подъезде
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [title_ru] => Недвижимость
        [description_ru] => Объявления по недвижимости, продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, комнат. Тут, вы быстро найдете себе крышу над головой!
        [meta_desc_ru] => Объявления по недвижимости, продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, комнат. Тут, вы быстро найдете себе крышу над головой!
        [meta_key_ru] => продажа квартир, съем или сдача квартир, съем или сдача комнаты
    )
)
```

не могу понять как, потому что тут 3 массива, не понимаю как правильно составить цикл

Comment: у вас тут не три массива, а вложенные массивы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто откликнулся, пока ждал ответа, я вышел на улицу освежил кипящий мозг. Когда вернулся и прочитал ваши ответы, и тут отдельное спасибо teran'у, он натолкну меня на вариант который мне полностью подошел!

```
       foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key] = array(
                'id' => $value['id'],
                'title' => $value['title_'.$_SESSION['lang']],
                'description' => $value['description_'.$_SESSION['lang']],
                'meta_desc' => $value['meta_desc_'.$_SESSION['lang']],
                'meta_key' => $value['meta_key_'.$_SESSION['lang']]
            );
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать простой цикл по элементами массива, а результаты следует добавлять в новый массив (`$data` - ваш  исходный массив)

```
$result = [];
foreach($data as $d){
    $result[] = [
                   'id' => $d['id'], 
                   'title_ru' => $d['title_ru'],
                   'description_ru' => $d['description_ru'],
                   'meta_desc_ru' => $d['meta_desc_ru'],
                   'meta_key_ru' => $d['meta_key_ru']
                 ];
}
```

Также вы можете использовать функциюю [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function($d){
             return [
                   'id' => $d['id'], 
                   'title_ru' => $d['title_ru'],
                   'description_ru' => $d['description_ru'],
                   'meta_desc_ru' => $d['meta_desc_ru'],
                   'meta_key_ru' => $d['meta_key_ru']
                 ];
          }, $data);
```

Также возможен и подход, когда вы простой пройдетесь по исходному массиву,а также его вложенным элемента, и удалите ненужное с помощью [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unset.php), а также прочие вариации.

Comment: А если ключей, оканчивающихся на `_ru`, будет не три а тридцать? :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev  когда будет, тогда и спросите :) к вашему ответу в целом такого же рода вопрос можно задать

Comment: Локаль - это отдельная сущность, эти ваши регулярки тут не нужны, нужно пересмотреть структуру данных.

Comment: Ув. teran спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 3):

Например так:

```
$original = [/* ... */];
$filtered = [];
foreach ($original as $block_key => $block) {
    $filtered[$block_key] = array_filter($block, function ($key) {
        return ($key === 'id') || preg_match('/_ru$/', $key);
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}

var_dump($filtered);
```

А вот и [рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/VelDH8) на IDEOne.